# How can I change different UINavigationBar Style in a UINavigationController?

Tags: ios

I want to change the color and translucent of the `UINavigationBar` in one viewController without influence on other viewControllers. It seems impossible because they share a common `UINavigationBar`. Some similar questions tell me to change the style of `UINavigationBar` in `viewWillAppear` and restore it in `viewWillDisappear`.But I can see the effect is not perfect. I want to know how can the follow app can do this. It seems it does not share a common `UINavigationBar`

[image]

Comment: As Lumialxk pointed, these are two independent navigation controllers. The one with a white bar was not pushed onto the one below it. It is being presented as a child view controller of the view controller below it, or something else underneath that we can not see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all you want to do is change the colour, here is what you can do:

**Simply animate the colour change:**

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.8 animations:^{
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor: [[UIColor orangeColor] colorWithAlphaComponent: 0.1]];
    }];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.8 animations:^{
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor: [[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent: 0.1]];
    }];
}
```

**Click the GIF below  for illustration:**

[image]

Comment: @seguedestination Typically all you need is the viewWillAppear colour animation. The destination view controller will have the same but will specify its own colour.

Comment: If you pan the pushedVC to pop the first VC. You will see the `UINavigationBar`'s color is changing because in the first VC, `viewWillAppear` is called and the code is excuted. Now if you still pan the view you can see the `UINavigationBar` is changed. It is different from my example.You can see I pan the viewController, but the NavigationBar is white, and the first one is still red!

Comment: @seguedestination yes. Thats because your implementation and what is in that screenshot are two different things. The screenshot probably has a custom written slider. I have written one myself but I don't know if it is applicable to your case or not. What is that apps name and I will have a look and tell you what they did

Comment: So, the only way is using two different navigationBar, and custom the present transition animation, Am I right?

Comment: @yes you are right. But you will not do it in 5 minutes. At least a day for something proper and solid.

Comment: @seguedestination what is the name of the app that you wish to mimic.

Comment: The name is Taobao, a online shopping app. It is developed by Alibaba. When I check my order, I take this screenshot.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have mastered the transition animation. Now I custom the transition make the present animation like "push" with two navigationController.

Comment: @seguedestination am happy you were not scared to try it.

Answer (score 0):

Because those two view controllers are in separate navigation controllers, allowing different colours for each.

Comment: How to push a new navigation controller? push navigation controller is not supported, but present is supported. Should I custom the push animation when I present a navigation controller?

Comment: @seguedestination Lumialxk is right. Those are two independent navigation controllers. And no, pushing a navigation controller is not supported.

Comment: @pnizzle thanks, I know that. So how the app can "push" a UINavigation Controller?

Comment: @seguedestination You add navigation controller `B` as a child view controller of navigation controller `A`. Then you add the B.view to A.view. It involves more code than just just pushNavigationController (which apple handles for you through the sdk)

Comment: @seguedestination It's just like push, you can customize segue to do that.

Comment: @pnizzle you means`[self.navigationController addChildViewController:navigationController];[self.navigationController.view addSubview:viewController.view];` ?

Comment: @seguedestination similar yes. But i am not saying you should do that, as I do not know what your app is meant to be doing. And you need to position and setup the view to end up with something usable. You need to add panning gesture recognisers and animations etc. So it is not as straight forward as just simply those two lines you stated

Comment: @seguedestination see my answer on how you can make your colour change better.